# Should I implement IDisposable on these samples

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, idisposable

Sample 1. (If one of my method uses unmanaged object)

```
Public Class Logger
     'Implements IDisposable <<< is this necessary because of unmanaged object inside the method?

     Public Sub CreateLogFile(ByVal msg As String)
        Try

           If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_LogDir) Then
             Try
               Using objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Format(Now, "MM-dd-yyyy HHmmss") & ".txt", True)
                   objWriter.WriteLine(msg)
                   objWriter.Close()
                End Using
             Catch ex As Exception

             End Try
           End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Sample 2. ( If I declare an event in the windows form)

```
Public Class frmViewerReport
    'Implements IDisposable <<< is this necessary because of event I added in the winform?

    Public Event DoneAutoPrint()
    Public Event Progress()
    Public Event ProgressDone()
    Public Event ErrorRaised(ByVal msg As String)
End Class
```

Sample 3. (if my class uses a class that has a dbcontext based class)

```
Public Class MyRepository
    'Implements IDisposable <<< is this necessary because of dbcontext?

    Private _ctx As New MyEntities
    Private _User As User
End Class

Public Class MyEntities
    Inherits DbContext
End Class
```

I knew there are a lot of topic regarding this matter, I could not find concrete sample on when and when not.

A yes/no answer would be helpful.

Comment: Ask only a single question per post.

Comment: run Code Analysis and it will tell you which classes should implement it.